# Databricks JSON column

Tags: python, azure-databricks

In Databricks I've a Json data in a column. I want to read JSON data in each record, find if JSON column is exists and if exists I want to change the value and update it in the same record column. Can some please help?

check if number column is exists
if exists update the number "XXXXXX"

JSON:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfXEx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xG41U.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using pyspark sql types converting those json to dict object by mention the schema.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json

phoneNumberSchema = StructType([
    StructField('type', StringType(), True),
    StructField('number',StringType(), True),
])
schema = StructType([
    StructField('firstName', StringType(), True),
    StructField('lastName',StringType(), True),
    StructField('gender', StringType(), True),
    StructField('age', StringType(), True),
    StructField('address', MapType(StringType(),StringType()), True),
    StructField('phoneNumbers', ArrayType(phoneNumberSchema), True),
])

df = df.withColumn("JSON_payload", from_json("json_object", schema))
```

Answer (score 0):

regexp_replace may be a solution if the column is a string and the schema of the json evoluate consistently